# What is Tuplizer in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, tuplizer

I came across a post that mentioned Tuplizer in NHibernate, can anybody provide a good definition or reference for Tuplizer?

Answer (score 6):

From [ITuplizer's source code](http://fisheye3.atlassian.com/browse/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Tuple/ITuplizer.cs?r=3313):

> A tuplizer defines the contract for
> things which know how to manage a
> particular representation of a piece
> of data, given that representation's
> EntityMode (the entity-mode
> essentially defining which
> representation).
>
> If that given piece of data is thought
> of as a data structure, then a
> tuplizer is the thing which knows how
> to:
>
> - create such a data structure
>   appropriately
> - extract values from
>   and inject values into such a data
>   structure
>
> For example, a given piece of data
> might be represented as a POCO class.
> Here, it's representation and
> entity-mode is POCO.  Well a tuplizer
> for POCO entity-modes would know how
> to:
>
> - create the data structure by
>   calling the POCO's constructor
> - extract and inject values through
>   getters/setter, or by direct field
>   access, etc
>
> That same piece of data
> might also be represented as a DOM
> structure, using the tuplizer
> associated with the XML entity-mode,
> which would generate instances of
> XmlElement as the data structure and
> know how to access the values as
> either nested XmlElements or as
> XmlAttributes.

In the [words of Fabio Maulo](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/10/16/less-than-gof-is-hbm.aspx):

> The tuplizer defines how to transform a Property-Value to its persistent representation, and viceversa a Column-Value to its in-memory representation, and the EntityMode defines which tuplizer is in use.

Some things you can do with custom tuplizers:

- [Remote lazy loading](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1363571/Remote-Lazy-Loading-in-Hibernate) (the article uses Java Hibernate but the general concepts apply to NHibernate as well)
- [Seamlessly mapping/persisting interfaces instead of POCOs](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/10/12/less-than-few-is-gof.aspx)
- [Mapping/persisting F# records](http://bitbucket.org/robertpi/functionalnhibernate/src/tip/src/app/FunctionalNHibernate/FSharpRecordTuplizer.fs) (from the [FunctionalNHibernate project](http://strangelights.com/blog/archive/2009/12/20/1650.aspx))

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks the above verbiage might be actually understood only AFTER one already knows what a tuplizer is?

Comment: @rapt it is kinda hard to grok, but check out the examples.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it might help to understand what a tuple is, first:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple

Python is most notable for having first class support for Tuples, though some other languages do as well (F#)

http://diveintopython3.ep.io/native-datatypes.html#tuples

and of course!

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=tuples

Answer (score 1):

**org.hibernate.tuple.Tuplizer**, and its sub-interfaces, are responsible for managing
a particular representation of a piece of data given that representation's
**org.hibernate.EntityMode**. If a given piece of data is thought of as a data structure, then a
tuplizer is the thing that knows how to create such a data structure and how to extract values
from and inject values into such a data structure. For example, for the POJO entity mode, the
corresponding tuplizer knows how create the POJO through its constructor. It also knows how to
access the POJO properties using the defined property accessors.
There are two high-level types of Tuplizers, represented by the
**org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizer** and
**org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentTuplizer** interfaces. EntityTuplizers are
responsible for managing the above mentioned contracts in regards to entities, while
ComponentTuplizers do the same for components.