# Hibernate Tuplizers

Tags: java, hibernate

In Hibernate 3.x documentation I came across the concept of Tuplizer: [Tuplizers](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-tuplizers)

I am new to Hibernate and I am trying to understand the concept of it and its advantages but I am facing difficulty with the explanation given there. Can you please help me with some examples or references on what tuplizers are?

Comment: Visit this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391332/what-is-tuplizer-in-nhibernate) it will helpfull for you ...

Answer (score 3):

It's a pretty advanced concept and unlikely to be of any use to someone just dabbling in Hibernate for the first time but the gist of it is that a tuplizer lets you completely customise the way your entities are created and represented and how properties are set and retrieved on them.